# Partially visible Action Mode Icons android

Tags: android, android-actionmode

I have just update android support library from `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1` to `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1`. It changed the appearance of action mode icons. Now they are half-visible/pressed as shown in the picture.

[image: Action mode Icons]

Is it a bug in the support library or I am doing something wrong?

Here is how I set the icons of action mode.

```
  @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

                menu.add("Delete").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_discard);
                menu.add("Copy").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_copy);
                return true;
            }
```

**Update**

I have verified this is a bug in android support library.

here is the link
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64207386

**Update**

Google updated the new release.
From `Recent Support Library Revisions` page.

> Bug fixes
>
> Menu icons are flattened on Support Library 26.0.0

Comment: Did you come right ? I have same issue

Comment: post the layout bounds picture

Comment: Are you Using Vectors or PNGs for your icons?

Comment: Could you add a link to the issue tracking the bug?

Comment: I have added the link

Answer (score 9):

Chances are there that it's becuase of less height than the icons require.

You can try this.

1. Add these two lines in values -> styles.xml -> Apptheme (style name must be only `AppTheme`).

   ```
   <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/actionButtonSize</item>
   <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/actionButtonSize</item>
   ```
2. And copy this style (in same styles.xml).

   ```
   <style name="actionButtonSize" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
       <item name="android:minWidth">30dp</item>
       <item name="android:maxWidth">48dp</item>
       <item name="android:width">38dp</item>
       <item name="android:minHeight">30dp</item>
       <item name="android:maxHeight">48dp</item>
       <item name="android:height">38dp</item>
   </style>
   ```

Also, sizes given here can be small or large as I've not tested them so set/adjust them according to your requirement.

And yes, if this doesn't work, please let me know, I'll provide more help.

Answer (score 4):

This is well tested code and it works very well.

Gradle dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
```

You can create menu.xml file in menu folder like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <!-- "Mark Favorite", should appear as action button if possible -->
  <item
      android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_name"
      android:title="Test"
      app:showAsAction="always" />

  <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
  <item
      android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_announce"
      android:title="Test"
      app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Here i have created test activity for your refernce

```
package edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;

/**
 * Created by darshan.mistry on 8/30/2017.
 */

public class DemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);

    Toolbar myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
  }

  @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.temp_menu, menu);
    return true;
  }
}
```

activity xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
      android:elevation="4dp"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
      app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
      />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is a bug in library, I am waiting for an update from google. I have updated my question.

Comment: I have already used library version 26.0.1 but i cannot found bug in actionbar icon.Have you tried above code if not than please try.

Comment: You are using widget.Toolbar. Maybe it works well with it. But with action bar it is not. By adding smaller icons the problem can be solved but official solution is coming in the next release.

Comment: Toolbar is updated component of Actionbar so instead of actionbar you used toolbar may be you issue resolved

Answer (score 2):

If you are using vector drawables as your icons, make sure they are of a small size, forget about those style stuff. It happens to me once, I had the width and height of my vectors like 500dp, if you reduce it to lets say 24dp by 24dp it will work.

Comment: This is a bug in library, I am waiting for an update from google. I have updated my question.

Comment: it might be a bug, but having a small size icon works meanwhile, I just read the bug report and they say it is fixed in version 26.0.2., I think it is not released yet.

Comment: I want those 50+ for the bounty :D